# Authenticating to Monday.com API from Zapier

Tags: api, authentication, zapier, monday.com

I am building a intergration in Zapier (not a ZAP) to retrive dat from Monday.com  Monday uses an API key that is required to be passed in the header to authenticate requests.

In Zapier developer I have set up the authentication as API Key. I have set up a field api_key for the user to add their key.

I have set up the test get request and in the HTTP Headers tab have added the api_key

When I send the reqest authentication fails with the folloaing error

authentication failed: The app returned "Not Authenticated". What happened (You are seeing this because you are an admin): Stack trace: ResponseError: {"status":401,"headers":{"content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"},"content":"{"errors":["Not Authenticated"]}","request":{"url":"https://api.monday.com/v2?query=%7Bme%7B%7D%7D"}} at

The Authentication code is

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are sending API key as api_token header.
You need to send this API key as "Authorization" header of your request to monday.com.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwkzZ.png)